# Vue: How to use prop value inside component template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am using a generic file selector component from https://alligator.io/vuejs/file-select-component/ and now I want to be able to pass "accept" value also from outside. In other words, I wanna be able to do something like

`<file-select :accept="application/json,.json"></file-select>`

which should translate to

```
<input type="file" accept="application/json,.json"/>
```

But so far my attempts at binding the value of this prop to file input's accept attribute have all failed (e.g. using `{{ accept }}` or `this.accept`). I was wondering if I can directly use prop value inside my component's template. any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: As you can see in the `<file-select>` docs, there's no prop `accept`. So, that's not possible. You could create a custom component, just like the `file-select`, that haves that `prop`

Answer (score 2):

You can extend their component to add the `accept` property, but given it's such a small component, you might be better changing the code provided in the tutorial to add the `prop`.

Vue adds any [non-prop attribute to the root element](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Non-Prop-Attributes), so when you do `<file-select :accept="application/json,.json"></file-select>`, the `label` is getting that `accept` added as an attribute, if the `input` was the root, then that would work as you need.

To learn how to extend components, there's another [alligator.io tutorial on component composition](https://alligator.io/vuejs/composing-components/) that should help you understand how to achieve this in Vue. However, since the template isn't ready for this new prop, you'd need to fully override the html.

As mentioned, you can just use their example code to create your own component that takes in an `accept` prop and uses it in the correct place.
Extending might be more trouble than what is worth, still, good information to have.

Comment: Why would extending it be the answer? Especially when you can use props directly in a vue template? The best practice for this is to define the property, then use `:accept="propName"` in the template

Comment: Yes adding the prop directly is correct here. I mentioned extending, but for this example it isn't appropriate. But it would be the way to go if you're adding components through npm or any other package manager as I thought it would be. After seeing the article, I added the correct way to do it, but decided to leave the initial suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the native element of the FileSelect component and manually assign the accept attribute to it.

template:

```
<file-select ref="fileSelect"></file-select>
```

js:

```
mounted() {
    this.$refs.fileSelect.$el.accept = "application/json,.json";
}
```